# Как подключить Базу данных при переносе сайта с локальной машины на удаленный хостинг?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, yii2, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Перенос сайта с локальной машины на удаленный хостинг. Как подключить Базу данных (импортированную через phpmyadmin) к **Yii 2 with advanced application template** на удаленном хостинге? в какие файлы какие внести изменения?

- Хост:    test.mysql.ukraine.com.ua
- Логин:   test_yii
- Пароль:  ********

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После скачивания [Yii 2 with advanced application template 2.0.8](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/releases/download/2.0.8/yii-advanced-app-2.0.8.tgz) с официального сайта и распаковываем архив; в командной строке пишем **init**:

[image: Yii2-init]

после чего создается файл **yii-advanced-app-2.0.8\advanced\common\config\main-local.php**, в котором указаны настройки доступа к базе данных на локальном компьютере:

```
    <?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2advanced',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

подключаем нашу существующую базу данных, изменяя название (например - **y2**) в файле **yii-advanced-app-2.0.8\advanced\common\config\main-local.php**:

```
    <?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=y2',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

и проверяем подключение, перейдя по ссылке (предварительно запустив локальный  веб-сервер):

http://localhost/yii-advanced-app-2.0.8/advanced/frontend/web/index.php

[image: signup]

[image: signup-OK!]

Загружаем базу данных на удаленный сервер, смотрим настройки доступа в панели управления хостинга, и вносим изменения в файл **yii-advanced-app-2.0.8\advanced\common\config\main-local.php**:

```
    <?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=test.mysql.ukraine.com.ua;dbname=test_yii',
            'username' => 'test_yii',
            'password' => '76dk9fkr',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

после чего загружаем все файлы из директории advanced на удаленный сервер.

Answer (score 1):

В директории */config* существует файл db.php в котором прописываются параметры подключения. Вот [тут](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html) подробней.

Также можно сделать так, чтобы при загрузке сайта конфигурация менялась автоматически:

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
     $config['components']['db']['dsn'] = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=default';
     $config['components']['db']['username'] = 'root';
     $config['components']['db']['password'] = '';
} else {   
     $config['components']['db']['dsn'] = 'mysql:host=production;dbname=default';
     $config['components']['db']['username'] = 'root';
     $config['components']['db']['password'] = '';
}
```

Comment: db.php - отсутствует, вероятно его нужно создать (скачано -> https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/releases/download/2.0.8/yii-advanced-app-2.0.8.tgz)